# Отследить открытую программу в javascript

Tags: electron

Программа, написанная на electron js, должна понять, какая программа открыта, а именно должна определить, что открыт photoshop. Как я это могу сделать?

Comment: Надо как-то получить данные диспетчера задач -_- По-другому врядли выйдет

Comment: Кажется, это то, что вам нужно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033127/ — библиотека из принятого ответа вроде кроссплатформенная. Но есть ответы и без дополнительных библиотек.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty я для этой задачи сравнивал много библиотек и выбрал https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-list так как, в сравнении с ps-node, стабильнее, богаче вывод, под windows работает на 2 порядка быстрее за счёт использования fastlist